# Leading and Trailing '0' gives error

Tags: python, integer, octal

```
random.randint(50,9)
```

or

```
random.randint(5,09)
```

give errors, although just

```
random.randint(5,9)
```

..works!

Leading and trailing zero's aren't allowed in python without converting it to string or using x.f formatting?

Comment: "50" is not a "trailing" zero.  That's 50, which is larger than 9.  What are you asking?  What is a "trailing" zero?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

oh, dear. "Trailing" zero gives error because [first argument to `randint` should be smaller than the second](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randint).

Leading zeros are used to represent octal numbers in python-2.x as in many other languages.

Comment: +1 for being polite on the "tailing zero" business.  I'm totally baffled by what "trailing zero" could even mean other than 10x.

Answer (score 0):

A leading `0` means that the value is an octal literal, but `09` is not a valid octal number.

Answer (score 0):

09 is not a valid dec integer in the second case
and in the first case - you have to give the function the lower number first